# Get out all inner array's properties

Tags: javascript

I have an Object like this:

```
    let myObj = [{
       xyz: {
          0: {
             id: 1,
             name: "Pimba"
             //....
          }
       }

      },
      {
        xyz: {
          0: {
             id: 2,
             name: "Xablaw"
             //....
          } 
        }    
      }
];
```

I need to get all properties from inner array and place it one level up. Like this:

```
    let myObj = [{
       xyz: {
          id: 1,
          name: "Pimba"
       }

      },
      {
        xyz: {
          id: 2,
          name: "Xablaw"
        }    
      }
];
```

Is that even possible? Tried to work with `map()` without successs.

Comment: is `xyz` an object with key `0` or an array?

Comment: Sure, its possible. But please show us some actual input and expected output.

Comment: @Neal It's an Array. @rmn The output is the last code. I just need the properties outside that inner array. But I can not do it without a bunch of ugly `for()`

Comment: If it's an array it should be surrounded with `[]`, `{}` is for objects. Can the array have more than one element, or is it always just a `0:` element?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let myObj = [{
       xyz: {
          0: {
             id: 1,
             name: "Pimba"
             //....
          }
       }

      },
      {
        xyz: {
          0: {
             id: 2,
             name: "Xablaw"
             //....
          } 
        }    
      }
];  

console.log(myObj.map(t => ({xyz: t.xyz[0]})));
```

```
 myObj = myObj.map(t => ({xyz: t.xyz[0]}));
```

if there are more then the 0 indexes, you can merge objects with this:

`myObj.map(t => ({xyz: Object.values(t.xyz).reduce((a,b) => Object.assign(a,b),{})}));`

Comment: I still have the inner array =\

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro I have no inner array

Comment: This is the right solution, unless you have more than 1 element in the `xyz` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var myObj = [{
    xyz: {
        0: {//Properties Here - Inner Array}
            a: 1,
            b: 2
        }
    }
},
{
    xyz: {
        0: {//Properties Here - Inner Array} 
            a: 1,
            b: 2
        }
    }
}];

var res = myObj.map(function (current, index, arr) {
var keys = Object.keys(current.xyz);
        for (var k in keys) {
            var inner = current.xyz[k];
            delete current.xyz[k];
            var innerKeys = Object.keys(inner);
            for (var i = 0; i < innerKeys.length; i++) {
                var innerK = innerKeys[i];
                current.xyz[innerK] = inner[innerK];
            }
        }
        return current;
    });
    
 console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can do this by doing `obj.map(item => shiftUp(item.xyz, "0"));`

Where shiftUp is a function defined as:

```
function shiftUp (obj, propName) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
        for (let prop in obj[propName]) {
            if (obj[propName].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                obj[prop] = obj[propName][prop];
            }
        }
        obj[propName] = undefined;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/will_russell_coactive/0xjb2cv6/